# Is there a way I should be calling this differently? I am following a book exercise

Tags: numpy

I am following a book exercise  which calls the function `np.average(samples_2d, axis=1)`.However when I try to do it on my end, knowing that the book wrote the code in the console and I am writing mines in IDE I adjusted likewise, but when I try to replicate the code I get this message  `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Below is my code

```
import numpy as np

samples = np.random.normal(5,1.5, 1000)
samples_2d = np.random.normal(5, 1.5, size=(5, 5))



print(np.average(samples_2d, axis=1))
```

Comment: I works in my `ipython` session without problem.

Comment: Did you use spyder or did you put it in console?

Comment: Console.  Was this the full error? Or was there a traceback?